# iOS4: Can't Programmatically Scroll to Bottom of UITextView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview, ios4, uitextviewdelegate

Before I was using this method....

```
//TextView is a UITextView 

[TextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([TextView length], 0)];
```

...which would programmatically scroll to the end of the UITextView but it doesn't seem to be working in iOS 4.0.  Is there a way to programmatically scroll to the end of a UITextView without changing editablility or inserting a point (where the user can tap on the UITextView and have a keyboard show up)?

Also, do I need to assign the file owner as the delegate? Does it make a difference?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Does it scroll at all? Is the keyboard being evoked?

Comment: When using


[TextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([TextView.text length], 0)];

It does not scroll at all, but it does not change the .editable of the textview (which is good for me).

A sample project demonstrating this is at 

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8256776/Bugsy.zip

it is a ViewController template with a UITextView and two buttons.

when one button is pressed it adds "\nFive" to the UITextView and attempts to scroll down to the end (unsuccessfully).

when the other button is pressed it adds "\nSix" to the UITextView and attempts to scroll down to the end (unsuccessfully).

Comment: what do you mean by unsuccessfully? Are you testing this on the simulator? I see the textview scrolling to the bottom... If I scroll it to the top, when I press five or six it scrolls to the bottom. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

UITextView doesn't have length property. 
Following code works good for my environment.

```
[TextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([TextView.text length], 0)];
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer didn't work for me, but following what you would use for a TableView works perfect. Just make sure your UITextView is named textView.

```
if (textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.size.height)
{
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height);
    [self.textView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly (and I've tried all kinds of variations of scrollRangeToVisible in my app!)

Comment: This seemed to work better than the other, accepted answer! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In IOS8, a call to ensureLayoutForTextContainer seems to make this solution work.. Took me nearly an hour to track this down.

```
    logObject.layoutManager.ensureLayoutForTextContainer(logObject.textContainer)

    logObject.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, logObject.contentSize.height), animated:false)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
[_myTextView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:_myTextView.textContainer];
[_myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([_myTextView.text length], 0)];
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use it works fine. The *shouldScrollTextToBottom* is set by the calling view (1 view controller lower in the calling stack)

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{ // scroll to bottom if required
  if(shouldScrollTextToBottom)
    [txtMyTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, txtMyTextView.frame.size.width, txtMyTextView.frame.size.height * 6) animated:YES];  
}
```

6 is an arbitrarily large number which should be a multiple of the UITextView's height. I have found that with a value of 5, my view does not scroll to the absolute bottom.